# How to make the progress html 5 element <progress> responsive using CSS

Tags: html, css

How to make the progress html 5 element  responsive using CSS . I do not hv the provision to use bootstrap, as I am working on a legacy app.Do I use Media query?

I did try @media( max-width: 768px). But I could not get apt results.

Comment: in which way you want to have it responsive? e.g. you can set the parents element width to 100% and the progress bar to width 80% it will grow or shrink itself

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried and describe in what way it is not giving the result you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example